# Getting an assertion error when trying to plot error bars on a histogram

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram, errorbar

I'm attempting to plot a histogram with 30 bins, from randomly generated data. I should add that I am still quite new to programming. The x-values (vals) are generated as follows:

```
import STOM_higgs_tools
vals = STOM_higgs_tools.generate_data() # A python list.
#print(vals)
# Each list entry represents the rest mass reconstructed from a collision
```

The histogram is then plotted as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # Making plots.
import numpy as np # Random number generation.
# Make a histogram.
bin_heights, bin_edges, patches = plt.hist(vals, range = [104, 155], bins = 30)
# Add the error bars
bin_height_sqrt = np.sqrt(bin_heights)
half_bin_width = 0.5*(bin_edges[1] - bin_edges[0])
plt.errorbar(half_bin_width, bin_heights, yerr=bin_height_sqrt, fmt='none')
plt.ylabel('Number of entries')
plt.xlabel('$m_{γγ}$ (GeV)')
plt.show()
# bin_heights and bin_edges are numpy arrays.
# patches are the matplotlib bar objects, which we won’t need.
```

The histogram itself is plotted just fine (if I remove the code related to trying to plot the error bars). This is what the plot looks like without the error bars.
[image]

The range is set [104,155] to only take data from within that range to plot on the histogram. The error bars should be sized by the using the square root of the height of the bins (bin_heights)
However, upon trying to add the error bars, I get an assertionerror

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Sidharth\Documents\Computing Labs\Computing Lab Session 3\statsgroupproject.py", line 102, in <module>
    plt.errorbar(half_bin_width, bin_heights, yerr=bin_height_sqrt, fmt='none')

  File "C:\Users\Sidharth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2524, in errorbar
    return gca().errorbar(

  File "C:\Users\Sidharth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1565, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Sidharth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 3382, in errorbar
    xo, _ = xywhere(x, lower, noylims & everymask)

  File "C:\Users\Sidharth\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 3285, in xywhere
    assert len(xs) == len(ys)

AssertionError
```

I don't know how to resolve this. The module imported in the beginning is custom made, defined as (if relevant) follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(1)

N_b = 10e5 # Number of background events, used in generation and in fit.
b_tau = 30. # Spoiler.

def generate_data(n_signals = 400):
    ''' 
    Generate a set of values for signal and background. Input argument sets 
    the number of signal events, and can be varied (default to higgs-like at 
    announcement). 
    
    The background amplitude is fixed to 9e5 events, and is modelled as an exponential, 
    hard coded width. The signal is modelled as a gaussian on top (again, hard 
    coded width and mu).
    '''
    vals = []
    vals += generate_signal( n_signals, 125., 1.5)
    vals += generate_background( N_b, b_tau)
    return vals


def generate_signal(N, mu, sig):
    ''' 
    Generate N values according to a gaussian distribution.
    '''
    return np.random.normal(loc = mu, scale = sig, size = N).tolist()


def generate_background(N, tau):
    ''' 
    Generate N values according to an exp distribution.
    '''
    return np.random.exponential(scale = tau, size = int(N)).tolist()


def get_B_chi(vals, mass_range, nbins, A, lamb):
    ''' 
    Calculates the chi-square value of the no-signal hypothesis (i.e background
    only) for the passed values. Need an expectation - use the analyic form, 
    using the hard coded scale of the exp. That depends on the binning, so pass 
    in as argument. The mass range must also be set - otherwise, its ignored.
    '''
    bin_heights, bin_edges = np.histogram(vals, range = mass_range, bins = nbins)
    half_bin_width = 0.5*(bin_edges[1] - bin_edges[0])
    ys_expected = get_B_expectation(bin_edges + half_bin_width, A, lamb)
    chi = 0

    # Loop over bins - all of them for now. 
    for i in range( len(bin_heights) ):
        chi_nominator = (bin_heights[i] - ys_expected[i])**2
        chi_denominator = ys_expected[i]
        chi += chi_nominator / chi_denominator
    
    return chi/float(nbins-2) # B has 2 parameters.


def get_B_expectation(xs, A, lamb):
    ''' 
    Return a set of expectation values for the background distribution for the 
    passed in x values. 
    '''
    return [A*np.exp(-x/lamb) for x in xs]


def signal_gaus(x, mu, sig, signal_amp):
    return signal_amp/(np.sqrt(2.*np.pi)*sig)*np.exp(-np.power((x - mu)/sig, 2.)/2)


def get_SB_expectation(xs, A, lamb, mu, sig, signal_amp):
    ys = []
    for x in xs:
        ys.append(A*np.exp(-x/lamb) + signal_gaus(x, mu, sig, signal_amp))
    return ys
```

**EDIT 1**

[image]

**EDIT 2**

```
# Make a histogram.
bin_no=30
bin_heights, bin_edges, patches = plt.hist(vals, range = [104, 155], bins = bin_no)
# Add the error bars
half_bin_width = []
for i in range(30):
    half_bin_width.append((bin_edges[i]+bin_edges[i+1])*0.5)
bin_height_sqrt = np.sqrt(bin_heights)
plt.errorbar(half_bin_width, bin_heights, yerr=bin_height_sqrt, fmt='none')
plt.ylabel('Number of entries')
plt.xlabel('$m_{γγ}$ (GeV)')
plt.show()
```

I was able to fix it with the above code, using a for loop to define the centre of the bins.

[image]

Comment: What version of matplotlib is this? User-facing code should absolutely not assert like that, and [those lines are proper checks with `ValueError`s now](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py#L3365-L3366). I see the same code in the latest release of matplotlib that I have installed.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to modify your `half_bin_width` slightly. Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

vals = []
vals += np.random.normal(loc=125, scale=1.5, size=400).tolist()
vals += np.random.exponential(scale=30, size=100000).tolist()
    
bin_heights, bin_edges, patches = plt.hist(vals, range=[104, 155], bins=30)
half_bin_width = 0.5*(bin_edges[1:] + bin_edges[:-1]) #making x and y the same size
bin_height_sqrt = np.sqrt(bin_heights)
plt.errorbar(half_bin_width, bin_heights, yerr=bin_height_sqrt, fmt="none")
plt.ylabel('Number of entries')
plt.xlabel('$m_{γγ}$ (GeV)')
plt.show()
```

[image: histogram with error bars]

Comment: This somewhat worked, but the error "bars" are all concentrated away from my actual data. See the edit in the main question.

Comment: It must be some other issue? I adapted your function to get vals like you might have and my graph looks fine. Look at my edited response.

Comment: I was able to fix it in the end. I changed my definition of half_bin_width slightly by adding in a for loop. Check edit 2 in the main question if you are interested to see what I did. Thank you for the help!